# Representations of $SO(4) \times SO(2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

In a paper I'm reading the representations of $\mathrm{SO(4)} \times \mathrm{SO(2)}$ play an important role. Specifically, the $(\mathbf{4},\mathbf{1})\oplus(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{2})$ is considered. I understand it may be a silly question, but I don't quite understand what is meant by this. Does it refer to a direct sum of representations, where $(\mathbf{4},\mathbf{1})$ is shorthand for $\mathbf{4}_\mathrm{SO(4)} \otimes \mathbf{1}_\mathrm{SO(2)}$ (with a similar interpretation of $(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{2})$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bf4$ means fundamental representation of $SO(4)$.

$\bf2$ means fundamental representation of $SO(2)$.

$\bf(4,1)$ means fundamental representation of $SO(4)$ and trivial representation of $SO(2)$.

In general, $\bf(n,m)$ means that object in $\bf n$ of $SO(4)$ and  $\bf m$ of $SO(2)$.